# Import encrypted AES key into Android Keystore and store it under new alias

Tags: java, android, security, cryptography, keystore

I am just familiarizing myself with the Android Keystore API.
I found out that the following features are available:

> - At least on some devices the Android Keystore is hardware backed, meaning that crypto operations run in a secure environment (TEE).
> - When the keystore is hardware backed, private RSA keys as well as secret symmetric keys that have been created within the Keystore can
>     be configured to never leave the Keystore and the raw keys cannot be
>     read out even with root access.

I am wondering now if the following is possible:

> 1. Generate a Public/Private key pair where the private key never leaves the Keystore
> 2. Upload the public key of this pair to a server
> 3. On the server: create a random symmetric AES key and encrypt it with the public RSA key uploaded by the user
> 4. On the device: Download this encrypted AES key
> 5. Import it into the hardware backed Keystore such that it is decrypted in there with the private key of the pair and stored under a
>      new alias
> 6. Use this new key alias to perform symmetric encryption and decryption

1-4 should be possible, the missing link for me now is point 5. in this list. Can some one help me out and tell me if this is possible at all and/or point me to the correct API reference?

I found this:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Vault/src/com/example/android/vault/SecretKeyWrapper.java

But it looks to me as if the unwrapping of the secret key happens in the normal environment and the decrypted AES key would be available in the App, which would not satisfy my security requirements.

**Update:**

I created a small test project using the linked `SecretKeyWrapper` and here are two code snippets:

The first one does the following:

> 1. Create a random AES key (not within in the keystore, this is what would happen on a server later). Obviously the raw key can be retrieved from the generated `SecretKey` object what isn't a problem since the server can know the key.
> 2. Encrypt/wrap the key with a RSA public key that was created in the client's Android Keystore (this would also happen on a server).
> 3. Decrypt the key again with the RSA private key (this would happen on the client and actually happens within the TEE in the example).

Snippet 1:

```
SecretKeyWrapper secretKeyWrapper = new SecretKeyWrapper(this,"testKeyRsa");

// Generate a random AES key (not in the keystore) [1]
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGen.init(128);
SecretKey secretKeyGenerated = keyGen.generateKey();
byte[] secretKeyGeneratedRaw = secretKeyGenerated.getEncoded();

// wrap this key with the RSA key from the keystore [2]
byte[] wrappedKey = secretKeyWrapper.wrap(secretKeyGenerated);

// unwrap it again with the RSA key from the keystore [3]
SecretKey unwrappedKey = secretKeyWrapper.unwrap(wrappedKey);

// the raw key can be read again [4]
byte[] unwrappedKeyRaw = secretKeyGenerated.getEncoded();
```

What I want to achieve is that the unwrapped key from [3] is stored in the Keystore with a new alias without returning the raw key. Of course I could easily import the `SecretKey` object into the Keystore here, but the problem is, that at this point the raw key can be retrieved from the object with the statement [4] what induces a security flaw. It is clear that the unwrapping/decryption already happens in the Keystore/TEE, since the private RSA key that is used for the decryption lives in the Keystore and cannot be retrieved.

If I compare this to the situation where a random secret AES key is created in the keystore, I notice that different types (implementing the `SecretKey` Interface) are returned. In the above example, the type is `SecretKeySpec`, whereas for keys which are returned from the Android Keystore (see snippet 2 below), "opaque" types are used where the `getEncoded()` method always returns null. In the following example, the type of `keyAesKeystore` is `AndroidKeyStoreSecretKey`.

Snippet 2:

```
// create a new AES key in the keystore
KeyGenerator keyGenAndroid =  KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES","AndroidKeyStore");
keyGenAndroid.init(
    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("testKeyAes",
         KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)                             
        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)                             
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
        .build());
        SecretKey keyAesKeystore = keyGenAndroid.generateKey();

// this returns null
byte[] keyAesKeystoreRaw = keyAesKeystore.getEncoded();
```

So to rephrase the question: Is it somehow possible to securely import a RSA wrapped AES key into the Android Keystore without revealing the secret key to the application?

**Update 2:**

@Robert makes the absolutely valid in the answer below that it actually does not matter if the unwrapping happens in the TEE or in the Rich OS (App) since the App (or a tampered version) could always later (after intercepting the wrapped key) just "use" the private RSA key from the Keystore to unwrap the AES key (without the need to access the raw private key at all).

Here is another thought though:
I found that it is possible to set Key Protection Parameters for keys in the Android Keystore (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProtection.html)).

The linked implementation for the `SecretKeyWrapper` does not use such protection parameters. After changing the `generateKeyPair` method as follows and adding the `PURPOSE_DECRYPT` and `PURPOSE_ENCRYPT` properties everything still works.

```
private static void generateKeyPair(Context context, String alias)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {
    final Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar();
    final Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar();
    end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 100);
    final KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT)
            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)

            .build();
    final KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
    gen.initialize(keyGenParameterSpec);
    gen.generateKeyPair();
}
```

I can now protect the RSA key such that it cannot be used for decryption by removing the `PURPOSE_DECRYPT` property. As expected the `Cipher.unwrap` method stops working and throws an `Incompatible purpose` exception then.

So what I would need then is a protection property where the plain decrypt functionality is blocked but which allows such a "secure import functionality" I am looking for. Something like a "`PURPOSE_IMPORT`" which apparently does not exist.

Comment: Using symmetric algorithms like AES with AndroidKeystore require you to have and Android 6.0+ device.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, actually I am targeting only Android 6.1+ devices

Comment: The the linked source code should be fine. Don't mistake that the `AndroidKeyStore` AFAIK returns you special instances of SecretKey. Those instances refer to keys in the secure environment (not to the normal environment) - they just use the same API. Therefore some methods for exporting the key will not work (like `getEncoded`). You can only use the key.

Comment: I tried it out and you are right the Android Keystore uses it's own types implementing the `SecretKey` interface, however, the unwrap method of the cipher returns the "normal" `SecretKeySpec` type even if a key is used that lives in the Keystore and therefore the decryption happens in the TEE. I updated the question with the examples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for now exists, as of API level 28 (Android Pie).  To use you you need to:

- Create a wrapping key pair, an RSA key pair with purpose PURPOSE_WRAP_KEY.  You should also generate an attestation for the public key to verify that the private key is a keystore key, in secure hardware.
- Send the public key (and attestation) from your app to the server that will provide the wrapped symmetric key.
- On the server, you need to wrap the symmetric key.  This involves more than just encrypting it, because the wrapper needs to contain not just the key material but also the authorization list that defines how the key may be used.  This is done by packaging the key and authorization info in an ASN.1 DER-encoded structure, per the schema [documented here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/WrappedKeyEntry).  There's some sample wrapping code in the [CTS test](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/keystore/src/android/keystore/cts/ImportWrappedKeyTest.java#304).  Note that if this format seems excessively complicated (e.g. the optional "masking key"), it's because in a future Android release there will be a corresponding secure export function and the use cases for that require the additional complexity. The secure export function didn't make it into Q, but will probably make it into R.
- Send the wrapped key to the app, which must create a [WrappedKeyEntry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/WrappedKeyEntry) and use [Keystore.setEntry()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#setEntry-java.lang.String-java.security.KeyStore.Entry-java.security.KeyStore.ProtectionParameter-) to store it.

This should work on any device with API level 28.  However, if the device has a Keymaster version < 4 (see the attestation certificate to find out what version of Keymaster is present), then the unwrapping operation will return the wrapped key material to Android userspace.  Keymaster version 4 (or above) will keep the unwrapped material in secure hardware, but because lower versions don't have support for the wrapped key feature, it has to be sort of emulated.

What happens if you have a lower Keymaster version is that when you create a PURPOSE_WRAP_KEY key pair, what is actually requested of the secure hardware is a PURPOSE_DECRYPT key pair.  Then when you do the import, the keystore daemon uses this PURPOSE_DECRYPT private key to decrypt the secret from the wrapper, then it imports the secret into the secure hardware and wipes the userspace memory that held it.  So, the key material exists in the keystore daemon's memory for a fraction of a millisecond.  Again, if the device has Keymaster version 4+ it is only unwrapped inside the secure hardware and never leaves.

Comment: Thanks to your message and the links you attach, I was able to learn a little more about the PURPOSE_WRAP_KEY, which until now was unaware of its existence. Unfortunately there is hardly any information about it on its implementation, and the most interesting post that can be found today is yours. I suppose it is still early and the process is immature, but I would like to be able to implement it in my App and on my server with NodeJS.

It seems that it will be necessary to wait a long time until there are feasible options for it. If you have more information I would be very grateful!

Comment: Nice answer, still a little confusing on the "private key to decrypt the secret from the wrapper", should i save the private key to the keystore so that the keystore call decrypt the wrapper key, and how can i achieve that @divegeek

Comment: And i did't see the relevant code in the cts test code, Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: @dreamtale I don't understand your question about the private key.  When you create the wrapping key pair, the private key is kept in keystore, protected by the secure hardware. See the wrapKey method in the CTS test for an example of how to constructed the wrapped key blob.

Comment: This answer has great information but I think it's a bit misleading. If we consult the official documentation on this topic [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#ImportingEncryptedKeys), it says `Note: This feature is supported only on devices that ship with Keymaster 4 or higher.`, while this answer suggests that Android can handle cases when KM version is < 4 differently by itself. I can support the official docs' claim with my implementation of this feature, it fails with an error KM_ERROR_UNIMPLEMENTED when....[continued]

Comment: [continued]... when I try to securely import on my Poco F1 (KM version 3), the import fails with the error KM_ERROR_UNIMPLEMENTED. I've double checked my implementation (ASN.1, wrapping etc.) and I didn't find any differences from the CTS test so I presume the docs are correct. I'll try with a device with KM 4 and report back.

Comment: And an update - I tried on a different phone that shipped with Android 9 (Galaxy A40) and it returned a different error. This time the code was -1000 which means KM_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ERROR. I'll update for further fixes, but it seems like my assumption is correct, it doesn't work on phones < KM 4.0.

Comment: Any updates @GligorAtanasovski? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: @FahadS.Ali Late response but no updates, I never managed to get the whole process working.

Comment: Here's where I got to, not quite sure what I did after that. https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/198012629

Comment: This works on Pixel phones (although I rand the code from android unit tests, not the above code).

Comment: @divegeek As you mentioned that `e.g. the optional "masking key`, the masking is optional, but I see in the android documentation they haven't mentioned anything about it. Can you please point me the source to it. Since there is no parameter that tracks the information about masking key in the blob, so even if we use is it like its preshared thing among the two parties? and also is it like both parties agrees before in hand that whether they use mask key or not?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to achieve is not possible by simply using the AndroidKeystore. What you need is custom code that runs within the TEE.

The reason for this is simple: When you have set-up your app with an asymmetric key-pair stored in the AndroidKeystore and you receive the wrapped AES key it does not matter if the unwrapping takes place inside or outside the AndroidKeystore:

All keys of an app stored in the AndroidKeystore are usable by the app in the normal environment. Is is by design as you wouldn't be able to use them otherwise.

Hence if the asymmetric key-pair is usable by the app **the app is always able to unwrap the received wrapped AES key** (using code in the normal environment). Therefore it does not make any difference where the unwrapping takes place. You can not guarantee that someone had copied the wrapped AES key when the app received it and then unwrapped it using the asymmetric key from the AndroidKeystore.

Comment: Ok, I see. I totally missed the point you are making in your last paragraph. Absolutely makes sense. So what I would need then (if I cannot use my own Trustlet in the TEE) would be a pre-installed RSA key pair specifically intended for importing keys, that can only be used for importing keys to the Keystore not for "normal" decryption. I assume such a thing does not exist, right?

Comment: Another thought would be to use the KeyProtection parameters to forbid plain decryption with the RSA key. I updated the question again regarding this.

Comment: The only chance I see would be if Google would add a KeyProtection parameter that would allow to limit an RSA key for key import (and unwrapping). But that would still leave a chance for an attacker to create it's own RSA key and request an AES key from the server - this attack would be totally unrelated to Android, therefore you can't prevent it using Android security mechanisms.

Comment: I plan to use the Key Attestation feature which was added with Android 7 against this sort of attack. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation.html I know there are probably no devices yet supporting this, but it's a rather long term project and it wouldn't be a problem if only a handful devices was supported.